# using inheritance in akka actors

Tags: scala, tcp, akka

I am writing a TCP client server program using Scala/Akka.
Some of the actors on server side need to process TCP messages coming  clients.
I have used(copied) code that basically parses the received TCP messages and on reception on a delimiter character the message is sent to someone else.

since more than one actor uses this logic, I had abstracted it in baseTCP actor and inherited other actors from this.
I would like to add common code such as handling of Bound/Connected/CommandFailed etc in this base actor.
Is this kind of handling ok in Akka? Or is it discouraged? 
best regards,
Vishal

Comment: When you say inherit, you mean traits or actual extension?

Comment: I did an actual extension and not using trait

Comment: If you are extracting individual capabilities, I suggest (since you are in Scala) to look into traits rather than extensions: they mix nicer (and you can have multiple, which is what you seem to want?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible and one example that adhere to what you describe is PersistentActor. http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/#akka.persistence.PersistentActor which is a Subtype of Actor.

On my past company, we abstract more PersistentActor by extending it to have HashMap as state and some defined lifecycle state (like open, close, waitingForAck, termination).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to extending actor could be to use traits with self types. In the code below the trait defines a `_: Actor` self type which would allow you to access actor specific variables such as `self`, `context` and so on.

```
trait ActorTrait { _: Actor =>
  def commonMethod = self.path
}
```

This way you can also parameterize the trait:

```
trait ActorTrait[Parameterized] { _: Actor =>
  def commonMethod(parameterized: Parameterized): Long = context.system.startTime
}
```